# Postgis - How to find whether two circles based on two points overlap?

Tags: postgis

I can calculate the distance between two points using:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
  ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(54.5972850 -5.930119)')
, ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(54.516827 -5.958130)'),
false);
```

However, my goal is to create a rough circular zone (this can be square, hexagon, octagon .etc) around each point and then check if the zones overlap.

I am looking at [ST_Overlaps](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Overlaps.html) as a possible solution but I am not sure how to convert these points into polygons to be compared. My ideal result would be something like:

```
SELECT ST_Overlaps(
  ST_CreateCircularPolygon(geom1, 1000, 6)
  ST_CreateCircularPolygon(geom2, 10000, 4)
);
```

Where:

```
ST_CreateCircularPolygon(geomerty, metreRadius, numberOfRadialPoints (e.g. 6 creates a hexagonal polygon))
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `quad_seg` parameter of `st_buffer` to specify the number of segments per quarter of a circle. That is, the total number of segments in the output will be a factor of 4.

To produce a square:

```sql
select st_asText(st_buffer(st_geomFromText('Point(10 10)'), 1, 'quad_segs=1'));
                      st_astext
------------------------------------------------------
 POLYGON((11 10,10 9,9 10,9.99999999999999 11,11 10))
(1 row)
```

Octagon:

```sql
select st_asText(st_buffer(st_geomFromText('Point(10 10)'), 1, 'quad_segs=2'));
                                                                                          st_astext                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POLYGON((11 10,10.7071067811865 9.29289321881345,10 9,9.29289321881345 9.29289321881345,9 10,9.29289321881345 10.7071067811865,9.99999999999999 11,10.7071067811865 10.7071067811866,11 10))
(1 row)
```

Since you want to work in meters but have unprojected coordinates, you can cast your geometry to geography, apply a buffer in meters and cast back to geometry. Let's note that `st_buffer` in geography will internally cast to a geometry in UTM, do the buffer, then cast back to geography (a lot of casting, but it's handy!)

That being said, a square is not a circle and it sounds very very wrong to assume otherwise. The orientation of the square is not obvious: should a corner be at the north? or should a segment be facing norht? or should the square be rotated? by how much?

You will save yourself a lot of trouble by using a real circle. In this case, don't use `st_buffer` at all, nor `st_distance` but rather `st_dwithin` which can leverage spatial indexes